# Accessing USB Drives from 'Computer'

Tags: c#, .net, fileinfo, file-copying

I'm trying to copy files over from the desktop to a USB drive programmatically. However, when trying to run this code, I am geting an error stating that part of the path could not be found:

```
if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    string selected = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);

    string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    string filefolder = @"\UpgradeFiles";

    string fileLocation = filePath + filefolder;

    if (!Directory.Exists(fileLocation))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(fileLocation);
    }

    else if (Directory.Exists(fileLocation))
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fileLocation);

        FileInfo[] fileList = di.GetFiles();
        foreach (FileInfo file in fileList)
        {
            string DrivePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(
                Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer);
            string CopyToDrive = comboBox1.Text;

            file.CopyTo(DrivePath + CopyToDrive, false);
        }
    }
}
```

The combobox contains the selected drive letter. Am I approaching this wrong when trying to add "computer\driveletter"?

Comment: Ain't nobody got time for that

Comment: @CallumBradbury Very good.

Comment: I thought so: firstly, don't use Path + Path when merging... paths, use Path.Combine, that will reduce your chance of errors and may very well be the problem here

Comment: secondly: you probably don't need the MyComputer path, you can just start out with the drive letter and go from there

Comment: @CallumBradbury I have tried just using the 'CopyToDrive' path, but it throws the same error message.

Comment: Another quick comment that isn't the answer: You dont want that else if(Directory.Exists), as it means the first time you run it it won't copy anything across as it will just do the CreateDirectory and then bail out

Comment: @CallumBradbury So would the best approach to be that `if !directory.exists` then just create the directory, pass the documents into that path and copy across from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your File.CopyTo(DrivePath + CopyToDrive, false) should be:

```
File.CopyTo(CopyToDrive + File.Name, false);
```

but with a bit of syntactic sugar like using Path.Combine or String.Format instead of just "+".

The issue is that File.CopyTo requires both the directory AND filename of the end location, when you're just providing the directory. This can be seen in the documentation for the method call here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f0e105zt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No problem, I guess in the end I did have time for that

Comment: As this is in my foreach loop, it'll copy all the files across from that location, correct?

Comment: Correct. You might want to add something to make them keep the same directory structure on the destination though, or any sort of folder structure in your source location will be flattened when it's moved to the USB drive.

Comment: Do you refer to a folder of some description or? Because they'll be copied from the same location each time, just as loose files.

Comment: If they're all just going to be in the same location without any sort of branching folder structure, it's fine as it is. I'm just a perfectionist when it comes to edge cases and that's one of the obvious ones. If it's not a scenario you see happening though, and all your files will just be in the root UpgradeFiles directory, then it's not a concern.

Comment: Yep, they'll all be copied from 'Upgrade Files' and pasted loosely into each Drive. So your answer will do just fine, thank you.